# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia vsync

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

How do I enable vertical sync with Nvidia video card in Ubuntu 14.04?

If I switch to Intel video card, then vsync works, and I can use vblank_mode environment variable to enable or disable vsync, but it's not working with Nvidia.

I've tried to add these two lines before X start:

```
export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"
export __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1
```

But it doesn't help, it just makes my fps three times lower.

I've also tried to find vsync setting in nvidia-settings, but there is only 3 things that I can change: Image Settings (Quality or Performance), checkbox for 'Use Conformant Texture Clamping' and antialiasing settings.

Sync to VBlank in Compiz, OpenGL settings either won't enable vsync.

Comment: Did you tried _NVIDIA X Server Settings_ (`nvidia-settings`)?